# JNI wrapper to read list from C++ and return to JAVA

Tags: java, c++, stl, java-native-interface

I have a requirement where I need to pass some values from C++ to JAVA using JNI. As per the requirement, input to c++ code is a line with list of points and I have to read x and y coordinates of each and every point and return to java code.I have declared a list as std::list> listofpoints; and reading x and y coordinates as

```
for(size_t j = 0; j < track->geometry.points.size(); ++j)
{

 PointZ &p = track->geometry.points[j]             listofpoints.push_back(std::pair<double, double>(p.vertex.position.x,p.vertex.position.y));
```

This geometry.points is to read each and point gets x and y coordinates. Now I am returning this listofpoints to JNI method. Here I have to write code so that it reads x and y coordinates and send it to JAVA method. I am finding a way to iterate list and get values but , i am finding it difficult to return from JNI to JAVA as JNI returns only jobjectarray. How can i convert this list to array in JNI and send to JAVA method. I am very much new to JNI and JAVA as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert the `std::list<std::pair<double, double>>` to a Java `List<Pair<Double, Double>>`.

Here is an example:

The Java method:

```
public static native List<Pair<Double, Double>> getList();
```

The C++ part:

```
std::list<std::pair<double, double>> myList{ // example input
    {1, 2},
    {3, 4}
};

JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_Main_getList(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls) {
    // First, get all the methods we need:
    jclass arrayListClass = env->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList");    
    jmethodID arrayListConstructor = env->GetMethodID(arrayListClass, "<init>", "()V");
    jmethodID addMethod = env->GetMethodID(arrayListClass, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");

    jclass pairClass = env->FindClass("javafx/util/Pair");
    jmethodID pairConstructor = env->GetMethodID(pairClass, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V");        

    // This is needed to go from double to Double (boxed)
    jclass doubleClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Double");    
    jmethodID doubleValueOf = env->GetStaticMethodID(doubleClass, "valueOf", "(D)Ljava/lang/Double;");

    // The list we're going to return:
    jobject list = env->NewObject(arrayListClass, arrayListConstructor);

    for(auto& coord : myList) {
        // Convert each C++ double to a java.lang.Double:
        jobject x = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(doubleClass, doubleValueOf, coord.first);
        jobject y = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(doubleClass, doubleValueOf, coord.second);

        // Create a new pair object
        jobject pair = env->NewObject(pairClass, pairConstructor, x, y);
        // Add it to the list
        env->CallBooleanMethod(list, addMethod, pair);
    }

    return list;
}
```

---

That said, it is probably easier to use a `std::vector` on the C++ side. Flatten the components of the `std::pair` into a `double[]`, and pass that back to java:

```
public static native double[] getList();
```

C++:

```
std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> myList{ // Now an std::vector
    {1, 2},
    {3, 4}
};

JNIEXPORT jdoubleArray JNICALL Java_Main_getList(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls) {
    size_t length = myList.size() * 2;
    double input[length];

    // Flatten pairs
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < length; i += 2, j++) {    
        input[i] = myList[j].first;
        input[i + 1] = myList[j].second;
    }

    // Copy into Java double[]
    jdoubleArray array = env->NewDoubleArray(length);        
    env->SetDoubleArrayRegion(array, 0, length, ((jdouble*) &input));

    return array;
}
```

Then on the Java side, you would do some further translations. For instance:

```
public List<Pair<Double, Double>> getTranslated() {
    List<Pair<Double, Double>> ret = new ArrayList<>();

    double[] list = getList(); // Calling our native method
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i += 2) {
        ret.add(new Pair<>(list[i], list[i + 1]));
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: it looks vector is looking simple. I will implement and let you know the result. Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: thats really working nice. But can you tell me how can i send jobjectarray instead of jdoubleArray.

Comment: @Kala, You would have to use `NewObjectArray`, and you can not put a `double` in it directly. Take a look here: [JNI Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html)

Comment: simply replacing NewDoubleArray with NewObjectArray works? what should be the jobject to this function? can u provide me some pseudo code please.

Comment: @Kala, It's not that simple. It goes like this: `get element class; call NewObjectArray with length and element class; Fill in array with SetObjectArrayElement;`.